# Image in Base64 coding is not displaying

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having an blob column in table with images. Images are saved, via command prompt image is shown as image name, via dump it's shown as stream resource.

I wanted to display image with the offer it is related to but I'm not getting image shown, just alt.

**Controller**

```
// Images
    $imgs=$imR->findAll();
    $img=array();
    foreach ($imgs as $i) {
        $img[]=base64_encode(stream_get_contents($i->getImage()));
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($imgs); $i++) { 
        $imgs[$i]->setImage($img[$i]);
    }
```

**Twig**

```
    {% for pic in imgs %}
      {% if pic.Offer.id == part.id %}
         <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{pic.Image}}"/>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Chrome developer tool**

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ZmlsZS01ZDQzZmE0NzRiNmI4LmpwZWc=">
```

**Dump before encode**

```
0 => Images {#1080 ▼
-id: 1
-Image: stream resource @840 ▼
  wrapper_type: "PHP"
  stream_type: "TEMP"
  mode: "w+b"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "php://temp"
  options: []
}
-Offer: Offers {#927 ▶}
```

}

**Dump after encode**

```
0 => Images {#1080 ▼
-id: 1
-Image: "ZmlsZS01ZDNlYmFjNDc4YTQ1LmpwZWc="
-Offer: Offers {#927 ▶}
```

Any ideas why images are not showing properly?
Pictures extension: jpeg

Comment: Try dumping out pic.Image, and testing it with an online tool like this: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter   -> Does it work? Maybe the data got truncated somewhere? The string in your included code is WAY too short to be a proper base64 image.

Comment: What does `$i->getImage()` return? why do you need to run `stream_get_contents` on it?

Comment: Actually, your Image is 32 characters long, which is a suspiciously "round" number for me. Maybe it gets truncated upon inserting to the database? Feels like it's the last 32 characters of a proper blob.

Comment: your base 64 data is the filename... `ZmlsZS01ZDQzZmE0NzRiNmI4LmpwZWc=` when decoded is `file-5d43fa474b6b8.jpeg`... you need to encode the image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with removing Base coding

**Controller**

```
// Images
    $imgs=$imR->findAll();
    $img=array();
    foreach ($imgs as $i) {
        $img[]=stream_get_contents($i->getImage());
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($imgs); $i++) { 
        $imgs[$i]->setImage($img[$i]);
    }
```

**Twig**

```
{% for pic in imgs %}
  {% if pic.Offer.id == part.id %}
    <img alt="Embedded Image" src="{{asset('offersImages/' ~ pic.Image)}}"/>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Displaying properly right now.

*Thank you for suggesting what is wrong*